# Probability of presence of at least one color blind person in a group

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

The frequency of red-green color vision defects among populations of Northern European origin
is around 8% of males and 0.5% of females.

> 1. Deeb S. The molecular basis of variation in human color vision: Variation in human color vision. Clinical Genetics.
>    2005;67(5):369-377. doi:10/cn5s4g

One souce I found for the probability of at least one color blind person in a group of three men is (https://jfly.uni-koeln.de/color/): $0.22 = 1-(1-0.92)^3$

Does that source do the correct calculation?
I think it should be $0.22= 1 -(1-0.08)^3$

How could I calculate the chance of presence of at least one color blind person in a group of two women and two men?

Would $0.16 = 1 - (0.92^2 * 0.995^2)$ be correct?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please let me know how I can improve my question

Comment: The original source typoed, $0.22=1-0.92^3$

Comment: OK I see your correction now. Yes that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're both correct. The source is calculating the probability of the opposite event (which is easier). Note $P(Event) = 1 - P(Opposite \space event)$. There you have it